# When is $\sin\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ purely real/imaginary?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

> Sketch the sets on which $\sin\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is purely real/imaginary.

My current result is that for purely real numbers $\sin$ is purely real and for purely imaginary numbers $\sin$ is purely imaginary but I am indecisive about complex numbers which have a real component $\neq 0$.

I came up with this using

$$\sin(x+\mathrm iy)=\sin x\cos(\mathrm iy)+\cos x\sin(\mathrm iy),\qquad x,y\in\mathbb R.$$

Let $y=0$ (purely real case) hence

$$\sin (x+\mathrm i\cdot 0)=\sin x\cdot 1+\cos x\cdot 0\in[-1,1]$$

which is obviously purely real. On the other hand let $x=0$ and $y\neq 0$ (purely imaginary case) thus

$$\sin(0 + \mathrm iy) = 0\cdot\cos(\mathrm iy)+1\cdot\sin(\mathrm iy) = \mathrm i\sinh y\in\mathbb C.$$

I do think that for arbitrary complex numbers $x+\mathrm iy$ the number $\sin(x+\mathrm iy)$ can be purely real sometimes but I couldn't come up with an explanation.

Based on those observations I would sketch the complex plane and draw the real line $(-\infty,\infty)$ for purely real outputs and the entire plane without the said line $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(x,0)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$ for purely imaginary outputs.

Edit: The proof I attempted was just for myself to verify my assumption - it seems as I don't have to give a proof for this exercise.

Comment: Hint: Try to show that $\cos(iy) = \cosh y$. Then, using the first equation you wrote, you'll end up have an expression of the form $\sin (x+iy) = f(x)g(y) + i u(x)v(y)$, and determining when this is purely real or imaginary follows from setting real and imaginary parts to zero.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Note that $x \in \mathbb{R}$, not $[0,2\pi)$. So $\sin$ is imagniary on the lines the lines $x = n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, not just $x=0$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 So assuming $y=0$ purely real for all $x$ and for $y\neq 0$ purely imaginary for $x=n\pi,n\in\mathbb Z$ as the real component vanishes, isn't it? Hence purely imaginary on $\{(x,y)\mid x=n\pi,y\neq 0,n\in\mathbb Z\}$ while purely real on $\{(x,0)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I'm afraid you seem to be conflating two different ideas. It's certainly true that $y = r \sin \theta$ where $\theta$ is the argument of the complex number, and $r$ magnitude. However, the question here is discussing the sine of the complex number itself, not of some angle associated with it. Perhaps [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Sine_with_a_complex_argument) could serve as a quick introduction to the concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the definition $$\sin(x+iy)=\frac{e^{ix-y}-e^{y-ix}}{2i}$$
$$=\frac{e^{-y}(\cos x+i\sin x)+e^{y}(i\sin x-\cos x)}{2i}$$
$$=\frac{i\cos x(e^{y}-e^{-y})}{2}+\frac{\sin x(e^y+e^{-y})}{2}$$
And then equate the real and imaginary parts to $0$.

Answer (score 4):

well,

$\begin{align}
\sin(a + bi) &=\sin(a)\cosh(b) + i\cos(a)\sinh(b)\\
 &=\sin(a)\frac{e^b + e^{-b}}{2} + i\cos(a)\frac{e^b - e^{-b}}{2}\end{align}$

So you have purely imaginary on evert $a=n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}.$